# Specify action to be performed at the end of many functions

Tags: oop, python

I have a python object in which a bunch of functions need to perform the same action at the end of execution, just before the `return` statement. For example:

```
def MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def update_everything(self):
        '''update everything'''
        pass

    def f1(self):
        #do stuff
        self.update_everything()
        return result

    def f2(self):
        #do stuff
        self.update_everything()
        return result

    def f3(self):
        #do stuff
        self.update_everything()
        return result
```

What is the best (pythonic?) way to do this, except for the explicit calls at the end of each function?

Comment: That should probably be `self.update_everything()`, btw.

Comment: You could write a decorator, but that would actually take *more* lines of code. You might be able to use a metaclass, but that would probably mean that *every* method in MyClass would always do that, which seems dangerous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, using a decorator is actually *more* code, but it does have the advantage that you can see that a method updates everything at a glance. It's a different kind of explicitness ;-)

```
def update_after(m):
    """ calls self.update_everything() after method m """
    def decorated(self, *args, **kwargs):
        r = m(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.update_everything()
        return r
    return decorated


def MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def update_everything(self):
        '''update everything'''
        pass

    @update_after
    def f1(self):
        #do stuff
        return result

    @update_after
    def f2(self):
        #do stuff
        return result

    @update_after
    def f3(self):
        #do stuff
        return result
```

Answer (score 6):

I think that any solution to your problem would be unpythonic, because (as Tim Peters says in the Zen of Python (`import this`)):

```
Explicit is better than implicit.
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the other way round?

```
class MyClass(object):
    def update(self, func):
        value = func()
        # do something common
        return value

    def f1(self):
        # do stuff
        return result

    def f2(self):
        # do stuff
        return result

my_object = MyClass()

my_object.update(my_object.f1)
```

Edit:
You could also write it in such way that `update` accepts a string being a name of the object's method. This would prevent running other objects' methods.

```
my_object.update('f1')
```